# Linux GPIO force interrupt

Tags: embedded-linux, raspbian, gpio

I have an application running on a Pi3, it has an interrupt produced from the rising edge of the pin.

This all works fine but my problem comes in testing the software. I have created a test harness application that simulates all other interfaces. What I would like to do in software is trigger the input interrupt for that pin.

The Pi is in a sealed box so I have no real hardware options.

So far I have tried working from the command line but when I try writing to the /gpio17/value it gives me the following:

> $ echo 1 > value
>   error: Operation not permitted

I know on a bare metal solution I would just write to a register to trigger it but can find nothing about this for Linux.

Comment: Could you add a description of the error?

Comment: On the command line I enter echo 1 > value and get write error: Operation not permitted

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code, otherwise this is the wrong site for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Got this sorted and apologies if the question wasn't clear enough. Just putting this up as FYI.

The basic setup of a GPIO on Linux using /sys/class/gpio is:

*echo 18 > /sys/class/gpio/export*

then

*echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/direction*

to set as input.

That is fine but what I found was that when I tried to set the value with

*echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value*

I got the error mentioned above (Operation not permitted).

So the solution was to let the Functional Application setup the pin and the ISR as an input, then with the Test Application reconfigure the pin to an output.

*echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/direction*

This then allows me to write to the 'value' variable and trigger the rising edge interrupt.

As a precaution I am moving the GPIO pin in use for testing away from the functional pin so as not to overdrive it in battle against the Pullups/ Pulldowns of the external hardware.

Note: I had tried using the /dev/mem mmap approach but this was not working very well and a couple of times got the interrupt to fire but would not stop. If I figure this out I will update.

Comment: I tried to change GPIO pin direction. I got this:
gpio417# echo out > direction
-bash: echo: write error: Input/output error
Driver did not implement the function to set direction to "out".

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

`$ echo 1 > value error: Operation not permitted`

This error comes because:

```
static ssize_t value_store(struct device *dev,
…
    if (!test_bit(FLAG_IS_OUT, &desc->flags)) {
        status = -EPERM;
```

I.e., kernel does not allow value to be changed if a GPIO pin's direction is `in`.

I removed this restriction and build a kernel for debug:

```
cat value
# value is 0 
echo 1 > value
cat value
# value is 0
```

The change has no effects.

Then I tried to change its direction:

```
echo out > direction
-bash: echo: write error: Input/output error
```

Investigating the kernel code, you can find this error comes because the `direction_output` function pointer in `struct gpio_chip` is not implemented.

Then I called `poll(2)` on another GPIO pin instead, whoes direction is `out`. At the same time, `poll(2)` with `POLLIN` event instead, because `POLLPRI` event will not happen, while `POLLIN` happens with every `poll(2)` because `value` is a regular file, not a pipe. More poll events help you debug easily.

Now you can `echo 1 > value` to debug.

Or you can overwrite the GPIO signal with a debug switch. E.g.,

```
if (access("/tmp/debug_switch", F_OK) == 0) {
    gpio_signal = <whatever you want>
}
```

When you want to overwrite the GPIO signal, run `touch /tmp/debug_switch`.